# Spring STS won't launch in Ubuntu 14.4

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04

I can't run 'springsts.exe' in Ubuntu 14.4. I have installed jdk8 and made it as default. After that, I downloaded the zip file and extracted and tried to open it by double-clicking on the STS executable file, but in vain.

The `java -version` command shows this result:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)
```

Is there anything wrong with my JDK installation? 
I installed it in this way: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

Answer (score 0):

You have downloaded the wrong file. `springsts.exe` is most likely a Windows executable.

I'm assuming that `springsts.exe` is a part of [Spring Tool Suite](http://spring.io/tools/sts/all).

Download the Linux version.